# Format £ sign with pandas to_html

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to format the output of a `DataFrame` with `to_html` so that the values are displayed with £ as a prefix.

```
df['gross'].map('£{0:,.0f}'.format)
```

Returns:

[Attempt with symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCyP2.png)

```
df['gross'].map('&#163;{0:,.0f}'.format)
```

Returns:

[Attempt with hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh07U.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add the £ symbol to the HTML output then don't alter the dataframe itself - you'll convert all your numeric fields to strings and lose the ability to treat them as numbers. `to_html` allows you to specify how to format things using the parameter `formatters`.

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = dict( index = ['A','B','C','D'], values = [1,2,3,4])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

format_pounds = dict( values = '£{}'.format) # add £ to column 'values'
html = df.to_html(formatters = format_pounds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are going wrong necessarily but you could try using the styler:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2], [3.2, 4.01]], columns=['gross', 'fish'])
s = df.style
s.format({'gross': "£{0:,.0f}".format})
s.render()
```

produces:

```html
<style  type="text/css" ></style>  <table id="T_97cbc3ba_cc03_11e8_8f0c_8c85905d0081" > <thead>    <tr>         <th class="blank level0" ></th>         <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >gross</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >fish</th>     </tr></thead> <tbody>    <tr>         <th id="T_97cbc3ba_cc03_11e8_8f0c_8c85905d0081level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>         <td id="T_97cbc3ba_cc03_11e8_8f0c_8c85905d0081row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >£1</td>         <td id="T_97cbc3ba_cc03_11e8_8f0c_8c85905d0081row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >2</td>     </tr>    <tr>         <th id="T_97cbc3ba_cc03_11e8_8f0c_8c85905d0081level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>         <td id="T_97cbc3ba_cc03_11e8_8f0c_8c85905d0081row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >£3</td>         <td id="T_97cbc3ba_cc03_11e8_8f0c_8c85905d0081row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >4.01</td>     </tr></tbody> </table>
```